# What is this chord in Schubert's D. 531?

Tags: piano, chord-theory, chord-progressions, chord-voicings, nonchord-tones

Consider following extract from Schubert's *Der Tod und das Mädchen* (D. 531) :
[image]

I assume that the indicated chord in the penultimate bar can be seen as a transition between the chords of D major and A major (voice leading). But can it also be seen as a real chord? Which chord would it be?

Answer (score 3):

It's a suspended chord - A7sus4, sometimes called A11. The bass is as the penultimate chord, A, there's no M3, but a sus (D) which drops to M3 (C♯), to end on a perfect cadence on the key chord, D major. Guessing that it starts in the parallel key of Dm.

Comment: Yes, it starts in the key of D minor (score: http://ks4.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/f/f1/IMSLP16210-SchubertD531_Der_Tod_und_das_M%C3%A4dchen.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In older theory it is an 11th. The notes written are the first (A), fifth (E), 7th(G) and 11th (D).